# Hide multiple rows depending on cell value in row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide multiple rows:

- If in a specific cell of the row there is a space or is empty, the row will be hidden.
- If it is hidden and there is anything else, the row will be shown.

The code needs to work on a specific worksheet as I have multiple worksheets where there is row to hide or columns to hide at a different place.

The Excel sheet:

[image: worksheet]

My goal is to hide rows between 8 to 37 if there is there is a space or if it is empty, depending what the code inside the cell points at for the cell A8 to A37.

If I activate the code, only the row 8, 9, and 10 should be visible, 11 to 37 should be hidden.

I tried these two pieces of code:

```vb
Sub C1()
   
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-06_Jeux Prod.")

Dim C As range

For Each C In range("A8:A37")

    If C.Value = " " Then
        C.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     
    Else
        If C.Value = Empty Then
            C.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
        Else
            C.EntireRow.Hidden = False

        End If
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

This code work as intended except that it is not tied to a sheet. `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-06_Jeux Prod.")` is not working as well as a couple other code I tried. They point to an error. So when I try to use this code it will work on the active sheet and not `FR-3-06_Jeux Prod`.

```vb
Sub Hide_column_and_Row_F_3_6()

Dim NbreLigne As Integer
Dim tableau As range

Set wrkshtDoc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-06_Jeux Prod.")
Set tableau = wrkshtDoc.range("A8:A37")

NbreLigne = tableau.Rows.Count

For k = 1 To NbreLigne
    If tableau(1, k) = " " Then
        tableau(1, k).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf tableau(1, k) = Empty Then
        tableau(1, k).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        tableau(1, k).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next k

End Sub
```

There is code in my file where I hide columns and I tried to reuse it.

I replaced "row" in the code with "column". It is hiding row with "test", line 8 only. It won't hide the empty cell.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to enhance your question.

Comment: Empty means empty. You have formulas in the `A` column, so no cell will ever be empty in it. But it may be blank i.e. its formula may evaluate to an empty string `=""` which you could most safely test with `If Len(Cstr(C.Value)) = 0 Then`. To include the space, you could write a single `If` statement: `If Len(Trim(Cstr(C.Value))) = 0 Then`. Also, if this code is located in the workbook containing the `FR-3-06_Jeux Prod.` worksheet, instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, use `ThisWorkbook`. Also, improve the `For Each` line with `For Each C In ws.Range("A8:A37").Cells`.

Comment: Can you clarify why the filter functionality wouldn't work for your purposes as it wouldn't require any code at all? It is possible to have a hidden column that contains a trigger, and a filter that looks for the trigger, and a blank cell to hide that row. Only rows where there is a trigger would be effected by the filter.

Comment: I am looking to use a button to hide all row that is not needed, eventually i want to use a button on my first sheet wich will trigger all the code trough all the sheet in my document. currently there is 9 sheet where there is information that i need to hide ans some of the sheet will be a a bit more harder to hide the necessary row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with code1, you only need to add:
For each C in ws.Range("A8:A38")

Because you add ws. in front of the Range, it knows which sheet to apply it on.

Good luck!

Comment: And for your second code, tableau(1,k) this is the same as Cells(row,column) so you need to switch the 1 and the k for all. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells

Comment: That what i was missing, also for the code 2 i found the problem which was that all (1,K) was inversed → (K,1)

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Blank Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideBlankRows()
       
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("FR-3-06_Jeux Prod.")
    
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In ws.Range("A8:A37").Cells
        Cell.EntireRow.Hidden _
            = IIf(Len(Trim(CStr(Cell.Value))) = 0, True, False)
    Next Cell

End Sub
```